# Ruby undefined method error in rake task, not working on fresh checkout of repo that works for everyone else

Tags: ruby

After checking out a fresh version of a repo, I find that I get an undefined method error in  a rake task that used to work for me and works for everyone else. The following code gets called, and throws this error: `undefined method 'source_index' for Gem:Module`. Yet `Gem.source_index` appears to be clearly defined.

```
module Gem
  def self.source_index=(index)
    @@source_index = index
  end
end

module Rails
  class GemDependency < Gem::Dependency
    attr_accessor :lib, :source, :dep

    def self.unpacked_path
      @unpacked_path ||= File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'vendor', 'gems')
    end

    @@framework_gems = {}

    def self.add_frozen_gem_path
      @@paths_loaded ||= begin
        source_index = Rails::VendorGemSourceIndex.new(Gem.source_index) // ERROR HERE
        Gem.clear_paths
        Gem.source_index = source_index
        # loaded before us - we can't change them, so mark them
        Gem.loaded_specs.each do |name, spec|
          @@framework_gems[name] = spec
        end
        true
      end
    end
```

Comment: Did you run the bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Rerunning `bundle install` worked.